# Get type of html elemnt on the click event of that element angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

my HTML is like this

```
 <input autocomplete="off" class="gui-input ai-validate" ng-click="isValid($event)" ng-model="prdElement.FreightData[0].FrtDesc" ng-required="prdElement.settings[0].isFreightData" placeholder="Freight Description" type="text">
```

and inside my controller I have wrote the function like this

```
 $scope.isValid = function ($event) {

       // I want to know whether clicked element is an input or select here
    };
```

inside this function I want to know whether the event came from an input or HTML select. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why dont you just debug that event and check the $event-Variable? Im pretty sure you will find it out pretty fast yourself then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : you can use `$event.tagName` to know the tag name of the html element for which function get called

```
$scope.isValid = function ($event) {

       // I want to know whether clicked element is an input or select here
       if($event.target.tagName=='INPUT' || $event.target.tagName=='SELECT')
          alert("this is "+$event.target.tagName+" html element");
    };
```

Comment: not working for me. I am getting "undefined" for $event.tagName

Comment: I think you missed about target, edited your answer. please let me know if i have made any mistakes in the code.